# How to filter class fields using objects.filter and the id=pk in django

Tags: django

I am trying to filter the title of a post so I can write the title into a file to track user activity. This is my code for writing in the file:

```
def cover(request,pk):

text = coverposts.objects.get(id=pk)
thistime = datetime.datetime.now()
Name = coverposts.objects.get(title__id=pk)
articlefile = open('useractivity.txt','a')
articlefile.write('\n'+ str(Name) + ', '+ str(thistime))
articlefile.close()
return render(request,'cover.html',{'text':text})
```

And this is the class I wish to get information from :

```
class coverposts(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 visual = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
 subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 body = models.CharField(max_length=100000000)
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(default =datetime.now(), blank= True)
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you please tell, what are you expecting from this line 'Name = coverposts.objects.get(title__id=pk)'.

Comment: I had wanted to pull the title for the model with an id=pk, i just wanted sure how to write the command. any advice?

Comment: Since you want to pull the title of the object with id=pk, you can make use of 'text', since it will be pointing to the coverposts object with id=pk. To get the title, you can print 'text.title', it will give you the title of the coverposts object with id=pk.